# Adding (meaningful) features does not improve model performance

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, overfitting, confusion-matrix

I am struggling with confusion matrices and their outputs. I thought to follow all the steps right, but unfortunately it seems that something is not going well.

I had a dataset built and labelled on my own. It shows a class imbalance so I decided to apply undersampling and oversampling, looking at F1-score and Recall as in many papers and on the web.
The steps were:

- split data in train and test (80/20)
- apply resampling only on train set
- apply pre-processing algorithm (BoW, TF-IDF, ...)
- use different classifiers to get results
- look at performance using confusion matrices (or alternatively ROC)

I tried with different features: in one dataset with less features engineering, i.e., using only features from Text, I got a maximum value of F1-score equal to 68%. With more features, that I thought to be significant for improving the model, I am getting max 64%, that is weird considering the problem (email classification for spam detection).
In theory, if I extract features only from text, I get a better score rather than extracting also features from email addresses.
I would like to ask you for some tips and suggestions, if you have any, as I think that this cannot be possible, as the expected results should be higher in the second case, when I consider also information from email address (number of dots, suffix, registration date,...).
Also, the confusion matrix, has given me weird outputs (look at 0s below, got using Kfold with 3 splits):

```
# With  RF 

   Total classified: 4696
Score: 0.9630948387237324
Score length 10

Confusion matrix:
[[2172  176]
 [   3 2345]]

# With LR  

Total classified: 4696
Score: 1.0
Score length 3

Confusion matrix:
[[2348    0]
 [   0 2348]]
```

I am thinking at a problem of overfitting or some other issues with model building.
An example of results is the following (for Logistic Regression model):

**Logistic Regression (including also numerical features)**

```
Total News classified: 4696
Score: 1.0
Score length 10

Confusion matrix:
[[2348    0]
 [   0 2348]]



             Logistic Regression
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

         0.0       0.96      0.97      0.97       585
         1.0       0.76      0.67      0.71        76

    accuracy                           0.94       661
   macro avg       0.86      0.82      0.84       661
weighted avg       0.94      0.94      0.94       661
```

**Logistic Regression (with only Text, so no extra numerical features)**

```
Total News classified: 4696
Score: 0.65
Score length 3

Confusion matrix:
[[2154  194]
 [  66 2282]]


Logistic Regression
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

         0.0       0.96      0.97      0.96       585
         1.0       0.73      0.68      0.71        76

    accuracy                           0.93       661
   macro avg       0.85      0.83      0.84       661
weighted avg       0.93      0.93      0.93       661
```

For defining `X, y, X_train, y_train, X_test` and `y_test`, I used the following code:

```
    X = train['Text'] # in case of numerical I added more variables: train[['Text', 'Num1', 'Num2']]
    
    y = train['Label']
    
    # Split into train/test sets
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=40)
   
    train_set = pd.concat([X_train, y_train], axis=1) 
    test_set = pd.concat([X_test, y_test], axis=1) 
    
    spam = train_set[train_set.Label == 1]
    not_spam = train_set[train_set.Label == 0]
    
    # Oversampling  
    oversample = resample(spam, 
                           replace=True, 
                           n_samples=len(not_spam), 
                           random_state=42)
    
    # Returning new train set
    oversample_train = pd.concat([not_spam, oversample])

    train_set = oversample_train.copy() 
    test_set = pd.concat([X_test, y_test], axis=1)
    valid_set = pd.concat([X_valid, y_valid], axis=1)
```

For selecting and extracting text features, I am running the following:

```
 countV = CountVectorizer()
    ct= ColumnTransformer(
        transformers=[('bow', countV, 'Text')],
        remainder='passthrough',
    )

#logistic

logisticR_pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('LogRCV',ct),
        ('LogR_clf',LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', max_iter=200)) 
        ]) 

logisticR_pipeline.fit(train_set.drop('Label', axis=1), train_set['Label'])
predicted_LogisticR = logisticR_pipeline.predict(test_set.drop('Label', axis=1))
np.mean(predicted_LogisticR == test_set['Label'])
```

Maybe I missed some steps or switched the order. I thought it was due to a classifier applied to the wrong dataset (train instead of set, but it does not seem to be caused by that).
What I think is that it is a problem of overfitting.

I would appreciated if you could tell me your thoughts on this.

Thank you for all your help.

---

See below the code that is returning the weird results in the confusion matrix. I had tried to follow steps from this link: https://www.pythonheidong.com/blog/article/743892/20cb290436b9ea7533af/ but now I am getting failed to open page.

```
def build_confusion_matrix(classifier):

for train_ind, test_ind in k_fold.split(train_set): # I am using my train set

        train_all = train_set.iloc[train_ind] # I think the error comes from this step
        train_y = train_set.iloc[train_ind]['Label']
        test_all = train_set.iloc[test_ind] # I think the error is also from this piece of code
        test_y = train_set.iloc[test_ind]['Label'] # train_set or test_set?
        
        classifier.fit(train_all,train_y) # this step needs to fit the model
# Make prediction
        c_predictions = classifier.predict(test_text) # it returns a matrix
        confusion += confusion_matrix(test_y, c_predictions)
        score = f1_score(test_y, c_predictions)
        scores.append(score)
        
# Calling function for my classifier
build_confusion_matrix(logisticR_pipeline)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're asking how it's possible to get an $F_1$ score of 68% despite getting a perfect or near-perfect confusion matrix and accuracy? Or are you asking something else (what)?

Comment: Hi Sycorax. Yes, for me sounds weird that I am getting a score of 1.0 after including more features in the model (previously I had only one Text var, then I added some numerical features and applied vectorisation to both in order to get only 1/0 values). In the model without numerical variables, I got 70% of F1 and in confusion matrix Prec: 0.72, Acc 0.93, Rec 0.68. Now, with also numerical features, I am getting very high scores but max F1 score 0.68, Prec: 0.75, Re 0.61 and Acc 0.93. I would have expected some improvement on F1 as this is the metric to look at in case of class imbalance

Comment: The order of steps was the same for both the models (with and without numerical features). I apply to both the dataset oversampling in order to get class balance. Might it be the case of oversampling or some other error that I am not spotting yet? Could it make sense to have perfect or near-perfect confusion matrix and accuracy with low values in F1 score and Recall (my main metrics in this binary classification with class imbalance), or it is a problem due to bad fitting or something else? I would need an improvement of my metrics F1-score and Recall and here, unfortunately, there is not.

Comment: Which datasets (train, oversampled-train, test) are those metrics reported for?  The confusion matrices do not match the classification reports.  What is score length, if you're using 5-fold cv throughout?  For that matter, where is the cv happening?

Comment: Consider not resampling your data. Most algorithms are very clumsy in generating new data and it is not a panacea. Instead, use a weighted loss function to train your classifier to do better at picking out the minority class.

Comment: Yes, I think your suggestion can make sense. However, I think the problem is not caused by oversampling here (at least for the confusion matrix). If I compare the results from `Logistic Regression (with only Text, so no extra numerical features)` and those ones from `Logistic Regression (with Text and extra numerical features)`, the difference is in the score. I should expect something that can give me approximately the same values, as the codes are very similar.The only difference is in the `build_confusion_matrix` function,at the steps that I commented. I think there is something wrong there

Comment: @val Please avoid asking the same question on [different sites](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/89679/64377) ([cross-posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/422674)).

Comment: The difference between the first code and the last one is probably this: I assume that in the last code `train_set` is the one obtained with `train_set = oversample_train.copy()` right? This means that the cross-validation is done with data after resampling, and this would certainly cause weird results: 1) the test set used at every fold is also resampled, so it's not the true distribution, 2) oversampling duplicates the instances of the minority class, so a good few instances end up in both the training and test set: this is a massive data leakage which makes the results completely biased.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know about cross-posting. Unfortunately I cannot delete this post as I have opened a bounty. I knew that if I apply oversampling I should apply it only on the train set, so I applied the resampling after splitting data. However, in the other case, when I consider `train_all = train_set.iloc[train_ind]['Text']`, after resampling, I get a score very close to the results from confusion matrix. Do you think it is also biased and unreliable as result? For building confusion matrix, I used the code from here: https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~elhadad/nlp16/spam_classifier.html

Comment: I tried with the not resampled training set. However I am still getting the same high scores (approx. 99%). I think that the problem is in `train_all = train_set.iloc[train_ind]['Text']`: if I include Text, it works ok (values around 65%); if I remove Text as in the case I shown above, then it goes to 99% / 100%